# How to distinguish koa ctx is multipart/form-data type or not?

Tags: koa, koa2

So i'm using koa2,
if this request is multipart type, believe i need to process

```
    ctx.request.body.fields
```

otherwise i process

```
    ctx.request.body
```

So what's the best way to distinguish and handle these 2 cases ?

Comment: To whoever gave me -1: if i know what to search, i won't ask question here. If you cannot understand my question based on these keywords, you are not qualified to write code.

Comment: Couldn't you check the `ctx.req.headers` and look at the `Content-Type`?

Comment: @saadq  i could, right now i can just check if ctx.request.body.fields is undefined or not. But given so many packages: koa-body, koa-bodyparser, koa-better-body ... i'm looking for the best way to do this.

Comment: You can also try console logging the ctx and then decide what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my point of view is, if you're needing to check for a form submission as well as other activity, then perhaps your endpoint is doing a bit much? It very much depends on your use case of course, but keeping form data and other content types separate may be a clearer API.

Having said that, I don't see any reason to get more complicated than checking for the presence of `fields`. `koa-body` is a great way to go about this.

One thing you might like to consider is using the middleware stack to your advantage. For example, only do stuff if there's a form submission but allow other actions to take place:

```js
router.post('/', koaBody({ multipart: true }),
  async (ctx, next) => {
    if (ctx.request.body.fields) {
      // Handle form if present
    }
    await next() // Pass control down the stack
  }
))
```